# MySQL order by hora

Tags: mysql, order-by

Em MySQL tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
2018-06-28 12:10:26
2018-06-25 11:10:26
2018-06-21 14:10:26
2018-06-31 00:10:26
2018-07-28 01:10:26
2018-07-29 09:10:26
```

São os dias de login de cada usuário (tem o campo ID mas desconsiderei para a minha dúvida), o cliente quer um dashboard que mostra a quantidade de logins em cada hora, fiz assim:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total, dia FROM acesso GROUP BY HOUR(dia)
```

Funcionou certinho, mas o que não estou conseguindo é dar um ORDER BY pela hora, para na hora de mostrar o resultado já vir ordenado, das 00hrs até as 23hrs, assim:

```
00 hrs - 23 acessos
01 hrs - 14 acessos
02 hrs - 18 acessos
etc..
```

Como ordenar? Nos meus testes está aparecendo fora de ordem.

Comment: O que esta sendo retornado para você atualmente?

Comment: @RobertodeCampos fica fora de ordem, até mostra os acessos por hora, mas não na ordem certa.

Answer (score 0):

Acabei conseguindo para quem tiver a mesma dúvida que eu:

```
SELECT COUNT(id) AS total, dia FROM acesso
GROUP BY HOUR(dia)
ORDER BY HOUR(dia) ASC
```

é o ORDER BY HOUR